# Calculating EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility in quantlib-python

Tags: python, r, rpy2, quantlib

I have R code that uses RQuantlib library. In order to run it from python I am using RPy2. I know python has its own bindings for quantlib (quantlib-python). I'd like to switch from R to python completely.

Please let me know how I can run the following using quantlib-python

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('library(RQuantLib)')
x = robjects.r('x<-EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="call", value=11.10, underlying=100,strike=100, dividendYield=0.01, riskFreeRate=0.03,maturity=0.5, volatility=0.4)')
print x
```

Sample run:

```
$ python vol.py 
Loading required package: Rcpp
Implied Volatility for EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility is 0.381
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `from quantlib import EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility`, and then calling it with the same arguments. See http://quantlib.referata.com/wiki/Python_QuantLib_tutorial (seems to be the sum total of their documentation)

Comment: @Thomas K: I can do this: `from QuantLib import EuropeanOption`     I was hoping for an explanation on how to set up a pricing engine for a given method of calculating vol. R takes a facade approach, python follows the original cpp Quantlib path of power and complexity, therefore my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll need a bit of setup.  For convenience, and unless you get name clashes, you better import everything:

```
from QuantLib import *
```

then, create the option, which needs an exercise and a payoff:

```
exercise = EuropeanExercise(Date(3,August,2011))
payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Call, 100.0)
option = EuropeanOption(payoff,exercise)
```

(note that you'll need an exercise date, not a time to maturity.)

Now, whether you want to price it or get its implied volatility, you'll have to setup a Black-Scholes process.  There's a bit of machinery involved, since you can't just pass a value, say, of the risk-free rate: you'll need a full curve, so you'll create a flat one and wrap it in a handle.  Ditto for dividend yield and vol; the underlying value goes in a quote.  (I'm not explaining what all the objects are; comment if you need it.)

```
S = QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(100.0))
r = YieldTermStructureHandle(FlatForward(0, TARGET(), 0.03, Actual360()))
q = YieldTermStructureHandle(FlatForward(0, TARGET(), 0.01, Actual360()))
sigma = BlackVolTermStructureHandle(BlackConstantVol(0, TARGET(), 0.20, Actual360()))
process = BlackScholesMertonProcess(S,q,r,sigma)
```

(the volatility won't actually be used for implied-vol calculation, but you need one anyway.)

Now, for implied volatility you'll call:

```
option.impliedVolatility(11.10, process)
```

and for pricing:

```
engine = AnalyticEuropeanEngine(process)
option.setPricingEngine(engine)
option.NPV()
```

You might use other features (wrap rates in a quote so you can change them later, etc.) but this should get you started.

Comment: You are Godsend Luigi Ballabio! It looks like above code is for as of now implied volatility. Is it possible to do it for some point in time in future/past?

Comment: You can set the global evaluation date to any date, if that's what you're asking. The code above will calculate the implied vol as of that date. Use `Settings.instance().evaluationDate = date` to set it.

Comment: Thank you again Luigi! I am reading python example I found in QuantLib-SWIG-1.7 and noticed minor differences from what you wrote. For example,  you have `FlatForward(0, TARGET(), 0.03, Actual360())` and SWIG has  `FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.05, Actual365Fixed())`. Could you help to understand the difference? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: I think this might be better asked in a new question, so that the information can be found more easily by others, too.

Comment: I am reading your book, Luigi, I am getting dangerously close to finding out the answer. I will post an extra question, if I fail. Thank you again!

Comment: @LuigiBallabio I know I am a quite late to asking this, but what is the purpose of the `sigma` (vol) passed to the `BlackScholesMertonProcess` here. Is it used somehow for the computation of `impliedVolatility`, if yes how does one arrive on that number as implied vol is something we're trying to compute?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the volatility won't actually be used for implied-vol calculation.  The process constructor needs it, though.